Fulcrum field data collector app and map file conversions
My business has started using Fulcrum to collect field data and I am having trouble with applying some map layers. We usually work with KML files in previous data capture platforms but Fulcrum don't support KML files for uploading map layers. I have tried converting KML to GeoJSON but it doesn't seem to be working. Is anyone familiar with the Fulcrum platform and navigated this issue before?
I used an online converter to convert KML to GeoJSON and copied this into the upload portal and it says the layer was created but I am unable to see it in the app view.
